# Influx DB precision setting at DB Level

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

Extension of [#8746](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/8746) :

I have tried to set the precision in the config file as seconds. But as i write data and tries to fetch it its again showing Nanoseconds timestamp.

I read the whole Doc but couldn't figure it out 
only change in my config file is:  `precision = "s"`

help me understand these things

How do I set the precision at DB level and how will I make sure I only get set precision timestamps in `epoch`. And I am using IST as timezone for my Application so also tell me how to set the same for InfluxDB in configuration

I am using `python-influxdb` client `seriesHelper` to write data into db and not specifying any time while writing data.

**Edit: Added a pull request to resolve this in influxdb-python SeriesHelper Class - [#502](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python/issues/501)**

Answer (score 1):

Set query parameter `epoch=s`. See [docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.3/guides/querying_data/#other-options-when-querying-data).

Query parameters are already supported by influxdb-python, for example:

```
client = InfluxDBClient(<..>)
client.query(<..>, params={'epoch': 's'})
```

Comment: I am using SeriesHelper class , and there was no option to set precision while writing. I added it and did a pull request into influxdb-python. I was doing that in order to improve query performance and avoid having to specify it everywhere.

Comment: When writing it would be `params={'precision': 's'}`, per docs.